# Testing __call method

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    if ( ! in_array($method, $this->validMethods))
    {
      throw new \BadMethodCallException("Not a valid method: {$method}");
    }

}
```

How do I test the `__call` method to make sure `$method` is in my list of valid methods? Right now here's what I did;

```
/**
 * @covers World\Transmission::__call()
 * @expectedException BadMethodCallException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage Not a valid method: foo
 */
public function test__callInvalidRequest()
{
    $m = m::mock('World\\Transmission', array($this->config))->makePartial();
    $m->foo(array('foo'));
}
```

The error I get is a endless trace of `call_user_func_array()`.

```
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!.
...
```

Comment: what is in your class: `World\Transmission`

Comment: http://bpaste.net/show/4jaevNSsQrXLVjxyIzF2/

Comment: if remove `$m->foo(array('foo'));`,  still reaches 100 nesting level?

Comment: It will now throw `Failed asserting that exception of type "BadMethodCallException" is thrown.`.

Comment: do you use `phpunit` test framwork?

Comment: Why are you mocking your fixture (the class to test)? Just test a concrete instance of it: `$m = new World\Transmission($this->config);` - I guess your nesting problem is caused by Mockery (even though I can't say exactly why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about simply change your test code to like these:

```
    public function test__callInvalidRequest()
    {
        $transmission = new World\Transmission($this->config);
        $transmission->foo();
    }
```

Comment: Haha, man, i don't know why I'm forcing myself to use a mock.